# Why is parallel stream slower?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was playing around with infinite streams and made this program for benchmarking. Basically the bigger the number you provide, the faster it will finish. However, I was amazed to find that using a parellel stream resulted in exponentially worse performance compared to a sequential stream. Intuitively, one would expect an infinite stream of random numbers to be generated and evaluated much faster in a multi-threaded environment, but this appears not to be the case. Why is this?

```
    final int target = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (target <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Target must be between 1 and 2147483647");
        return;
    }

    final long startTime, endTime;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(
        IntStream.generate(() -> new Double(Math.random()*2147483647).intValue())
        //.parallel()
        .filter(i -> i <= target)
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt()
    );

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Execution time: "+(endTime-startTime)+" ms");
```

Comment: Parallelizing petty tasks will always be slower. Multithreading has enough overhead that the task needs to justify the cost, or else you won't see any gains. Also, 1 test is meaningless. At the very least, stick this in a loop and take an average.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Apart of that I believe that Math.random() slows it down :-) Check my answer if interested.

Comment: Play with -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=<Number>, to change the common pool, and watch the results

Comment: Parallel streams are _usually slower_ for most use cases.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ya, I don't know why I asserted "always". I wrote that whole getting dressed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you added the qualifier "petty," which makes it closer to true -- you have to have either a really expensive task or a lot of inputs to run your task on or both.

Comment: You know there's a built-in `Random.ints()` stream to get a stream of random numbers?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: Your example hits several of the risk factors for poor parallelization.  First, `findFirst()` is tied to the encounter order of the stream, which hobbles the library's ability to parallelize (you should use `findAny()` instead.)  Second, you just don't do that much work per element, which means that the overhead of creating, scheduling, and coordinating tasks is likely to overwhelm the actual work.  Nor does the work-per-element exhibit much locality.  So the conditions for a parallel speedup are not really there.  (Also, your benchmark methodology is likely to give meaningless numbers.)

Comment: @Brian Goetz thanks for the clarification, I managed to fix it (see my answer below). Funnily enough I actually encountered this while watching your talk on "Thinking in Paralell" at Devoxx 2016!

Comment: `new Double(Math.random()*2147483647).intValue()` wastes performance, compared to `(int)(Math.random()*2147483647)`, just to hide the type cast that is still there…

Comment: @Brian Goetz: isn’t a stream generated by `IntStream.generate` UNORDERED right from the start? So there shouldn’t be any difference between `.findFirst()` and `findAny()`.

Comment: @Holger Yes, the result of `generate()` is unordered.  But the relationship between parallelism and encounter order is subtle, and is frequently a cause of failure to parallelize well.  So I felt it was worth bringing up this linkage even if it didn't apply to this *particular* code snippet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I totally agree with the other comments and answers but indeed your test behaves strange in case that the target is very low. On my modest laptop the parallel version is on average about 60x slower when very low targets are given. This extreme difference cannot be explained by the overhead of the parallelization in the stream APIs so I was also amazed :-). IMO the culprit lies here:

```
Math.random()
```

Internally this call relies on a global instance of `java.util.Random`. In the [documentation of Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) it is written:

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent
>   use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter
>   contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using
>   ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

So I think that the really poor performance of the parallel execution compared to the sequential one is explained by the thread contention in random rather than any other overheads. If you use `ThreadLocalRandom` instead (as recommended in the documentation) then the performance difference will not be so dramatic. Another option would be to implement a more advanced number supplier.

Comment: check out internal implementation of `Math.random()` - it's done with atomics, without any locks. it's hard to believe it introduces such a difference

Comment: Yeap, I've just checked it. But it really does introduce huge difference compared to the thread local random, just as the documentation states... :O

Comment: @SergeyFedorov, while atomics have no locks they can drastically reduce performance in atomic operation's do-while loops until the state is considered consistent. The problem is Unsafe.compareAndSwap() - they use busy waits inside.  In high contention cases cost raises exponentially and one is better off with synchronized blocks over a set of operations. Only tests can tell the best strategy. Well, ThreadLocalRandom will win every time over both approaches, of course.

Comment: Are you sure that CAS operations use wait? Any proof of that?

Comment: Well, in the context of a parallel stream operation, you shouldn’t use `ThreadLocalRandom`, but rather `new SplittableRandom().ints(0, 2147483647).parallel() …` to create the stream.

Comment: @Sergey Fedorov: CAS doesn’t use wait, but CAS may fail, in which case the calling code has to retry the operation (unless failing is an option). Repeated retries are like polling, which is what Alex Pakka called “busy wait”. It’s not a wait in the sense of putting the thread into a wait state.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of passing work to multiple thread is expensive es the first time you do it.  This cost is fairly fixed so even if your task is trivial, the overhead is relatively high.

One of the problems you have is that highly inefficient code is a very poor way to determine how well a solution performs. Also, how it runs the first time and how it runs after a few seconds can often be 100x different (can be much more) I suggest using an example which is already optimal and only then attempt to use multiple threads.

e.g.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
int value = (int) (Math.random() * (target+1L));
long time = System.nanoTime() - value;
// don't time IO as it is sooo much slower
System.out.println(value);
```

Note: this will not be efficient until the code has warmuped and been compiled. i.e. ignore the first 2-5 seconds this code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions from various answers, I think I've fixed it. I'm not sure what the exact bottleneck was but on an i5-4590T the parallel version with the following code performs faster than the sequential variant. For brevity, I've included only the relevant parts of the (refactored) code:

```
static IntStream getComputation() {
    return IntStream
            .generate(() -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2147483647));
}

static void computeSequential(int target) {
    for (int loop = 0; loop < target; loop++) {
        final int result = getComputation()
                    .filter(i -> i <= target)
                    .findAny()
                    .getAsInt();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

static void computeParallel(int target) {
     IntStream.range(0, target)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(loop -> {
                    final int result = getComputation()
                        .parallel()
                        .filter(i -> i <= target)
                        .findAny()
                        .getAsInt();
                    System.out.println(result);
                });
}
```

EDIT: I should also note that I put it all in a loop to get longer running times.

Comment: This isn’t a valid test, as you are now performing a parallel stream operation inside another parallel operation which turns the inner operation (the actual operation of your question) basically into a sequential operation, as the work is split in an entirely different way, i.e. the range `IntStream.range(0, target)` will be processed in parallel, not the random number sequences.

Comment: @Holger But I still get the results I expect, after testing on multiple machines. On a quad-core CPU the paralell version performs over 3 times faster than the sequential version for most numbers below 1000.

Comment: Actually I tried adding .parallel() to the sequential version and it was still slower, so turns out the the speedup is coming from the InstStream.range rather than the random number stream.