# Python: Parallel Processing in Joblib Makes the Code Run Even Slower

Tags: python, list, loops, parallel-processing, joblib

I want to integrate a parallel processing to make my for loops run faster.

However, I noticed that it has just made my code run slower. See below example where I am using `joblib` with a simple function on a list of random integers. Notice that *without* the parallel processing it runs faster than *with*.

**Any insight as to what is happening?**

```
def f(x):
    return x**x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(0, 10000)]


    # without parallel processing
    t0 = time.time()
    out1 = [f(x) for x in s]
    t1 = time.time()
    print("without parallel processing: ", t1 - t0)

    # with parallel processing
    t0 = time.time()
    out2 = Parallel(n_jobs=8, batch_size=len(s), backend="threading")(delayed(f)(x) for x in s)
    t1 = time.time()
    print("with parallel processing: ", t1 - t0)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
without parallel processing:  0.0070569515228271484
with parallel processing:     0.10714387893676758
```

Comment: Parallel processing involves additional overhead because of more complex setup. You normally don't want to parallelize tasks that take microsecond to complete.

Comment: I also tried it on a more complicated fuzzy matching function, and it still took a long time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the following simple parallelized code much slower than a simple loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727090/why-is-the-following-simple-parallelized-code-much-slower-than-a-simple-loop-in)

Comment: If indeed willing to understand **what happens** and **how to make faster processing**, definitely read argumentation and test-results in the above posted link. [PARALLEL]-scheduling does not bring speedups for free, so rather set yourself for a lot of learning about performance-motivated design tricks and for a lot of testing the actual add-on costs v/s a potential performance gains. **Indeed a thrilling domain.**

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `batch_size=len(s)` effectively says give each process a batch of s jobs. This means you create 8 threads but then give all workload to 1 thread.

Also you might want to increase the workload to have a measurable advantage. I prefer to use time.sleep delays:

```
def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return x**x

out2 = Parallel(n_jobs=8,
                #batch_size=len(s),
                backend="threading")(delayed(f)(x) for x in s)
```

> without parallel processing:  11.562264442443848
>
> with parallel processing:  1.412865400314331

Comment: With all due respect, Sir, adding sleep into f() is creating a false illusion, with respect to the Amdahl's Law. The [PARALLEL]-fraction ( here ) is so tiny, that [SERIAL]-part dominates and adding a sleep()-into the [PARALLEL]-section does not improve the processing performance, but skews the comparison of the composition of [SER]+[PAR]/1 v/s [SER]+[PAR]/N. The costs of [PAR]-Setup and [PAR]-Terminate overheads are the more "masked" by adding sleep().